# CoreAnimation layer causes WebView to not redraw properly

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

In a project I have been working on I wanted to use CoreAnimation layers to improve tableview rendering, however when i turned on Core Animation for certain layers it caused issues with my WebView.

https://github.com/jozefdransfield/TestWebView demonstrates a WebView inside a view displaying a large image. Which reproduces the issue I am seeing.

If View has Core Animation Layer checked then the WebView does not draw the image properly if you scroll within the webView, with it uncheck the webView behaves as expected.

Has anyone seen this issue before and have an idea how to fix/work around it. Or can you simply not mix webviews with CALayers?

Comment: Strange. I see no difference between "Core Animation Layer" checked & unchecked for the View (run on OS X 10.9).

Comment: Yeah i think its been fixed with 10.9